# Replace particular occurence of a word in string

Tags: c#, string, replace, cpu-word

Consider the following example : I have a string "word1 word1 word1 word1". and I want to be replaced 1st word1 and last word1.

How i can do this?

Comment: Which language are you using? Please provide more informations..

Comment: Which language are you using/intending to use, and what have you tried so far? It seems to me that you've done very little research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking to your other question I assume you use .NET, if so:

EDIT: This example will replace the first and last word:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string test = "word1 word1 word1 word1";
        Console.WriteLine(test);
        // Replace words
        test = ReplaceWords(test, "word1", "test");
        Console.WriteLine(test);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static string ReplaceWords(string input, string word, string replaceWith)
    {
        // Replace first word
        int firstIndex = input.IndexOf(word);
        input = input.Remove(firstIndex, word.Length);
        input = input.Insert(firstIndex, replaceWith);

        // Replace last word
        int lastIndex = input.LastIndexOf(word);
        input = input.Remove(lastIndex, word.Length);
        input = input.Insert(lastIndex, replaceWith);

        return input;
    }
```

Comment: Yes I am using .Net. But how can i replace these extracted words with another one?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a code that actually replaces the first and last word.